# MS SQL Update Query - Update all rows with that have the same field A to the top A value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

this should be easy, but I'm just not getting it.  I have a temp table that I'm populating from different sources.  In the temp table, I have a bunch of rows that might have the same subdivision name.  If the subdivision name is the same, then I want the top latitude and longitude for that subdivision to be in all rows for that subdivision.  I need to do it for all the subdivisions in the temp table that have an iSource = to 1 or 2.  The iSource field is the different sources. 0 is the most reliable, 4th there is not lat or long.

**Temp Table**

```
SubdivisionName  Latitude  Longitude  iSource
A                100       200        0
A                100       200        0
A                102       200        2
B                104       202        1
B                105       203        1
B                106       202        2
```

**Desired Result**

```
SubdivisionName  Latitude  Longitude  iSource
A                100       200        0
A                100       200        0
A                100       200        2
B                104       202        1
B                104       202        1
B                104       202        2
```

I tried this, but SQL Server 2005 doesn't like my prefixes TT or TTT.  Can you point me in the right direction?

```
WITH #TempTable
AS
(
SELECT TTT.*
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by SubdivisionName ORDER BY iSource) AS rnk
from #TempTable TTT WHERE iSource IN (1,2)
)
UPDATE #TempTable
SET FieldSheetLat = TTT.FieldSheetLat, Longitude = TTT.FieldSheetLong
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT TTT.*
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by SubdivisionName ORDER BY iSource) AS rnk
      FROM #TempTable TTT
)
UPDATE TT
   SET FieldSheetLat = CTE.FieldSheetLat, Longitude = CTE.FieldSheetLong
  FROM #TempTable TT
  JOIN CTE ON CTE.SubdivisionName = TT.SubdivisionName
              AND CTE.rnk = 1
 WHERE TT.iSource > 0;
```

Notes

1. The last filter is because there is no never a need to update any iSource = 0 rows
2. The UPDATE from JOIN pattern is used here, where the source is the `CTE where rnk=1` and the target is the `#TempTable` aliased as `TT`